# JJWT / Jackson alter the ObjectMapper used

Tags: java, spring, jackson2, jsr310, jjwt

For a project I am working on, I am required to use Spring Security and JSON Webtokens as provided by the library [io.jsonwebtoken (jjwt)](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). One of the claims I am required to add to my generated token is the following entity (simplified to illustrate the problem):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime ldt;
}
```

This works, but the resulting webtoken is serialized as following:

```
{
  "sub": "testuser@mydomain.com",
  "exp": 1523659655,
  "entity": {
    "name": testname,
    "ldt": {
      "hour": 0,
      "minute": 37,
      "dayOfMonth": 12,
      "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
      "dayOfYear": 102,
      "year": 2018,
      "month": "APRIL",
      "monthValue": 4,
      "second": 38,
      "nano": 569000000,
      "chronology": {
        "calendarType": "iso8601",
        "id": "ISO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This might not seem like a problem, but it is in fact a problem when later on I am required to map it to an instance of MyEntity again. After some reading online I figured that I need to change the configuration of the ObjectMapper, to change the configuration options (toggle the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`-flag to false). However, I cannot alter the configuration of the ObjectMapper used by jjwt as it's constructed like this (source of jjwt):

```
public class DefaultJwtBuilder implements JwtBuilder {
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    ...
}
```

Another option I found online was to put the following line in my application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
```

Yet to no avail, the ObjectMapper used by jjwt seems to ignore these properties.

What would I do to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jjwt documentation states that (from version 0.10.0 and on) you can inject your own `ObjectMapper` with a specific compile dependency and implementing the injection as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope> <!-- Not runtime -->
</dependency>
```

... then add the mapper to the `JwtBuilder`:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getMyObjectMapper(); //implement me
String jws = Jwts.builder()
    .serializeToJsonWith(new JacksonSerializer(objectMapper))
    // ... etc ...
```

as [documented here](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#json-jackson)

Comment: For those wondering how to implement the `getMyObjectMapper()`, this depends on how you manage dependency injection. If you're using plain old Java, a `return new ObjectMapper();` would do (with desired configuration); if you're using Spring, maybe that method returns an autowired instance. That's beyond the point of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by overriding the DefaultJwtBuilder, like this:

```
public class CustomJwtBuilder extends DefaultJwtBuilder {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
        .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .modulesToInstall(new JavaTimeModule())
        .build();

    @Override
    protected byte[] toJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }
}
```

And then creating the token like this

```
String token = new CustomJwtBuilder()
            .setSubject(..)
            .setExpiration(...)
            .compact();
```

Comment: I understand this answer was provided before JJWT 0.10.0 was released, but after 0.10.0, tete's answer on this page is the recommended solution.  JJWT users should follow that one.  Cheers!

Comment: @LesHazlewood I have accepted that answer; it was not possible yet when I originally asked the question.

Comment: I know, I said "I understand this answer was provided before JJWT 0.10.0 was released" :).  But thanks for updating the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally It happens when the compiler Unable to discover any JSON Serializer implementations on the classpath. Include the following jjwt jackson dependancy and rebuild the project. It solved my issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```